# Differences between sometimes and nullable in Laravel validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Let's assume I can do validation in two ways

```
 'active' => {
     'sometimes',
 }
```

and

```
 'active' => {
     'nullable',
 }
```

What's the difference? When the one will pass and the other won't?

And the same question about this:

```
 'user_id' => {
     'sometimes|exists:user,id',
 }
```

and

```
 'user_id' => {
     'nullable|exists:user,id',
 }
```

I've read multiple posts on a subject, including the documentation and I still don't get it. Does sometimes or nullable make even sense when using with no other rules (like in my first example)?

Comment: nullable is not the same as optional. `nullable` affects input that is there but may or may not be null. `sometimes` affects input that is not there

Answer (score 6):

Nullable:

Laravel converts empty value to null using middleware `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull`. Because of this, you will often need to mark your "optional" request fields as nullable if you do not want the validator to consider null values as invalid.

Sometimes :

If you want to validate the field only if the field is present in request. This is useful when we manipulate the DOM using javascript or jQuery.

[Read More](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation)